# Why are the addNode() methods returning the compile error "The method...in type...is not applicable for the arguments...", and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, tree

I'm trying to code a generic implementation of a ternary tree, and the tree's addNode method calls the parent node's setLeft, setMiddle, and setRight method, which are defined as follows:

```
public void setLeft(T item)
    {
        left = new TernaryTreeNode<T>(item);
    }
```

which is called in the addNode method as follows:

```
currentNode.setLeft(currentNode = new TernaryTreeNode<T>(data));
```

I'm not including the entirety of the code because it won't let me post the question if I do, and that line in the addNode method is where the error is. VSC's telling me that I can't use the child setter methods if I'm using TernaryTreeNode as the argument, but why is that? How do I fix it?

Comment: Hi Roxas, can you provide the exact error message and the line causing the error in your question? This will help others answer your question.

Comment: "The method setLeft(T) in the type TernaryTreeNode<T> is not applicable for the arguments (TernaryTreeNode<T>)"

The line causing the error is the second block of code that I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods `setLeft`, `setMiddle` and `setRight` take an Object of type `T` as argument, as you have stated. You are, however, trying to pass a `TernaryTreeNode<T>` as argument. You might have to either create methods that take a `TernaryTreeNode<T>` as parameter, or pass the object `T` contained in the node as argument. It's hard to decide which is correct, based on the information you have given, but one of those is most probably the wrong approach. Whether both are wrong is even harder to decide. ;)

```java
currentNode.setLeft(currentNode = new TernaryTreeNode<T>(data));
```

The above line passes a `TernaryTreeNode<T>` object instead of a `T` object.

As a more to the point comparison, what you are trying to do is akin to this:

You define:

```java
public void thisMethodTakesT(T item) { ...
```

But you call:

```java
thisMethodTakesT(new ArrayList<T>()); // This will produce a compile time exception.
```

`thisMethodTakesT` does not take lists, it takes one item of type `T`, not list of `T`s. Likewise your `setLeft` (and others) take `T` and not `TernaryTreeNode<T>`.

Comment: But...I still don't understand why I can't pass a `TernaryTreeNode<T>` into the method directly...isn't it a subclass of Object?

Comment: All classes are subclasses of `Object` in java, but that is not the problem here. You defined the signature of `setLeft` like this: `setLeft(T item)`, but you pass the wrong type of object. You try to pass `setLeft(TernaryTreeNode node)`. The argument in a method has to be at least as specific as the type expected. But `TernaryTreeNode` is not of type `T`. It does not directly or indirectly extend `T`. It *wraps* `T` (as a generic type parameter), which is something else entirely.

Comment: Ohhh, okay, that makes sense. I also realized that with the way I called the setter in the addNode method, if it had worked, it would have created a node *within* another node as opposed to a node *linked* to another node.